# Floating various shaped divs together into rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a large containing element with around ten DIVs inside - most are about 300px in width on average and are all set to float left. The end result is a widget/grid type layout. However, this style has been specifically built with responsive design in mind - we're using media queries to adjust the size and column count depending on device.

The issue is that we may have one or two boxes that are double-wide or double-tall. The double-wide doesn't really cause a problem with floating (that I can't solve anyway) but the issue is the double-tall. The double-tall would expand into the next row, but prevents other boxes from floating on the left of it. Float-right isn't an option because the tall box can't always be on the right.

I'm trying to find a way to dynamically figure out where each block can float to, like solving a puzzle. I've looked at a few javascripts like Masonry, jLayout, etc but they either don't work, or don't solve the problem of irregular boxes.

So:

1. I want to avoid absolutely positioning anything because we'd have to re-do that every time, for every element and they won't feel fluid.
2. I need to allow for double-wide and double-tall, but they may not always be present and eventually, users should be able to determine their location so we can't always just write javascript based on a known location.
3. I've tried moving around the elements via jQuery which does work, but has to be done on window resize, which is too much activity and results in elements flickering back and forth when you transition over the width that requires three columns to four.
4. Using css3 columns won't work because the DIVs are treated as text and are broken into two when they pass to the next column, and that doesn't allow for double-wide either.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Interesting problem can you give a simple code example illustrating the problem?

Comment: http://experiments.botsko.net/tests/dashboard/ - At large sizes there are four columns and everything looks great. But when the screen is adjusted to smaller sizes and it moves to three columns, the double-wide block affects floats in such a way that there's an empty spot. Shifting one or two boxes via javascript would work, but whatever we move in will leave an empty spot where they were, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still have not found any real way to handle the situation. For now I've just written some custom javascript to swap around a few DIVs when the page resizes.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you try my idea? or was it not what you were looking for?

Comment: It wasn't quite what I needed. I need to handle a variety of element orders so floating certain elements specifically wouldn't work. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

Use Jquery Masonry or Isotope, it'll arrange all the containers into the most space saving arrangement ( or if your using isotope, you can fiddle it around to prioritise other forms of arrangement)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't care too much about the order of your elements, a simple solution would be this:

1. Add your items to `#main` so that all `.tall` widgets are added first. Float `.tall` widgets to the right.
2. Likewise, make sure that all `.wide` widgets are added last and float these to the left.

It works in this case and I think will give you the most optimal use of space for any set of these elements.